# Tweepy Look up ID with username

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to get a list of IDs from a list of usernames I have. Is there any method that tweepy provides that lets me do lookup user IDs using their username?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twitter API has the resource https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup for such requirements. It can return user objects for at most 100 users at a time.

You can use [this in Tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/80015db395bdd19700390ed5d0742c7b6d5996d2/tweepy/api.py#L311) like:

```
user_objects = api.lookup_users(screen_names=list_of_at_most_100_screen_names)
user_ids = [user.id_str for user in user_objects]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
screen_name = unames['username']

    enter code here

#my username df
#0          briankrebs
#1       Dejan_Kosutic
#2     msftsecresponse
#3         PrivacyProf
#4            runasand

data = []
def return_twitterid(screen_name):
    print("The screen name is: " + screen_name)
    twitterid = client.get_user(username=screen_name)
    id = twitterid.data.id
    return id

for s in range(len(screen_name)):
    u_id = return_twitterid(screen_name[s])
    data.append(u_id)
print(data)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who landed here from Google, this is a code snippet that is basically a username to id converter. It supports twitter api V2.

```py
# the usernames variable is a list containing all the usernames you want to convert
usernames = ["POTUS", "VP"]
users = client.get_users(usernames=usernames)
  for user in users.data:
    print(user.id)
```