# download a list users from twitter

Tags: twitter, download

I have a list of "n" Twitter ID representing users I would like to download.
To retrieve their user profile info, should I use n times the api call get_user or there exist a method to pass the entire list and retrieve all the info within one single api call, within the twitter  rate time limit?

I tried something like 
api.search_users(A)
api.search_users(id in A)

where A contains the list of id
but it does not work.
Anyone helping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Twitter API resource https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup. It can return user objects for at most 100 users at a time.

You can use [this in Tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/80015db395bdd19700390ed5d0742c7b6d5996d2/tweepy/api.py#L311) like:

```
user_objects = api.lookup_users(user_ids=list_of_at_most_100_user_ids)
```

Much of this answer first appeared as part of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42946854/1921546